# Why does this division result in zero?

Tags: c, division, integer-division

I was writing this code in C when I encountered the following problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   int i=2;
   int j=3;
   int k,l;
   float a,b;
   k=i/j*j;
   l=j/i*i;
   a=i/j*j;
   b=j/i*i;
   printf("%d %d %f %f\n",k,l,a,b);
   return 0;
}
```

Can anyone tell me why the code is returning zero for the first and third variables (`k` and `a`)?

Comment: What errors are you getting? What do you expect the output to be? What output are you getting?

Comment: note that you've got /n instead of \n.  Is this a copy-paste of your code, or have you re-typed it?  Better to have a copy-paste to avoid transcription errors.

Comment: I've altered the title/question to what I think was intended

Comment: @therefromhere: you're just guessing and "fixing" the question doesn't help the asker learn how to ask better questions.

Comment: True, but might help the following people who google along those lines.

Comment: (I accept that this is pretty extreme edit, but it's such a common beginner's error I thought it was worth a stab)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What I think you are experiencing is *integer arithmetic*. You correctly suppose `l` and `b` to be 2, but incorrectly assume that `k` and `a` will be 3 because it's the same operation. But it's not, it's integer arithmetic (rather than floating-point arithmetic). So when you do `i / j` (please consider using some whitespace), 2 / 3 = 0.33333... *which is cast to an `int`* and thus becomes 0. Then we multiply by 3 again, and 0 * 3 = 0.

If you change `i` and `j` to be `float`s (or pepper your math with `(float)` casts), this will do what you expect.

Answer (score 11):

Are you asking why k and a show up as zero?  This is because in integer division 2/3 = 0 (the fractional part is truncated).

Comment: Expanding on that, when you write "a = <expr>;" with "a" declared float, it is only the *result* of <expr> that is casted to float. Since all the values and variables in your expressions are integer, the results are all based on integer arithmetic.

Comment: This goes for a as well, because he's doing the same operation there (i/j == (int)2/(int)3 == 0)

Answer (score 5):

You haven't said what you're getting or what you expect, but in this case it's probably easy to guess. When you do 'a=i/j*j', you're expecting the result to be roughly .2222 (i.e. 2/9), but instead you're getting 0.0. This is because i and j are both int's, so the multiplication and (crucially) division are done in integer math, yielding 0. You assign the result to a float, so that 0 is then converted to 0.0f.

To fix it, convert at least one operand to floating point BEFORE the division: `a = (float)i/j*j);`

Answer (score 4):

this is due to how the c compiler treats int in divisions:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
int i=2;
int j=3;
int k,l;
float a,b;
k=i/j*j; // k = (2/3)*3=0*3=0
l=j/i*i; // l = (3/2)*2=1*2=2
a=i/j*j; // same as k
b=j/i*i; // same as b
printf("%d %d %f %f/n",k,l,a,b);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're asking why k and a are 0: `i/j*j` is the same as `(i/j)*j`. Since j is larger than i, `i/j` is 0 (integer division). `0*j` is still 0, so the result (k) is 0. The same applies to the value of a.

Answer (score 0):

it doesn’t matter if you’re variable is float or not, as long you’re using

integer / integer , you’ll get 0,

but because you’re using a float output, you get 0.0