# Why does 5/7 print 0?

Tags: c, math, division, integer-division

I just started learning C, and I learnt that the / sign is the division operator.  I was experimenting, and was wondering why 5/7 printf the number 0.

Here is my program:

```
#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
    int n;
    n = 5/7;
    printf("%d", n);
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: because its output is integer only  `5/7` = `0.71..` = integer part is `0`. C (and many programming languages) works in this way. you need to learn `float` datatype also.

Comment: You've declared n as an integer. 5/7 is not an integer value.

Comment: `/` does [integer division](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerDivision.html).

Comment: Your might be interested in more general resources about C and read them first. The C FAQ covers your problem: http://c-faq.com/expr/truncation1.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does this division result in zero?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568337/why-does-this-division-result-in-zero)

Comment: there are so many duplicates of this here. How do you expect 5/7 to be stored in an int? n can't store values like 0.714285...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because of integer division.  `5/7` makes `0.71..`, and the integer part of this number is `0`, hence it prints `0`.  To solve this problem use `float` type (or double type) variables as well as constants for example try:

```
float f = 5.0 / 7.0;
```

print variable `f` with format string `%f`

Comment: As Beginner good answer, try to write complete answer. notice below @Daniel Daranas's answer. and also what I added

Comment: No my comment is to @C_Beginner_Learner

Comment: @C_Beginner_Learner being a friend, I edit for you (for OP I post a  comment, notice!), so that you can know `how to complete an answer?` (you answer was bit incomplete) --- also how to format, soon view this: [Help-center](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17782490/revisions)

Answer (score 3):

Because it is `0`.

`5/7` is an integer division, because both 5 and 7 are integers. The result of the integer division 5/7 is 0.

`n`, the variable which you assign the result to, is also an `int`.

You'd have floating point division if you wrote `5.0/7.0`. However, since you assign the result to n which is, again, an `int`, its value would be also 0. Of course, if you assign the result of `5.0/7.0` to a `double` variable, you get decimals in it.

Comment: No need to explicitly cast the two sides, you can cast only one side, the other will be implicitly cast.

Comment: @MarounMaroun No need, true, but I dislike using implicit casts.